# Is getting dropdown in MVC to bind to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have gone through many other versions of this question, but my attempt is just not working.  I have a notice model.

```
  public class Notice

  {
    [Key]
    public int NoticeId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string NoticeTitle { get; set; }
    public bool Public { get; set; }
    public NoticeType Type { get; set; }

  }
```

with a NoticeType Table

```
  public class NoticeType
  {
    [Key]
    public int NoticeTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
  }
```

I then populate the select list in my Get.

```
  public ActionResult Create()
  {
    List<NoticeType> _noticeTypes = db.NoticeTypes.ToList();
    SelectList noticeTypes = new SelectList(_noticeTypes, "NoticeTypeId", "Type");
  
    ViewBag.NoticeTypes = noticeTypes;
    return View();
  }
```

And the dropdown populates with my table data.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, ViewBag.NoticeTypes as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

But, the type value does not get passed to my Create post.

Please, can someone explain why.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix the class

```
public class Notice

  {
    [Key]
    public int NoticeId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string NoticeTitle { get; set; }
    public bool Public { get; set; }

     public  int NoticeTypeId  { get; set; }
    public virtual NoticeType NoticeType  { get; set; }

  }
```

and view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NoticeTypeId, ViewBag.NoticeTypes as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  That was driving me crazy.

Comment: I have to wait 4 minutes to accept the answer.

Comment: @Tom You are very welcome!